# Java date-time difference

Tags: java

```
long d1Ms = current_date.getTime();
long d2Ms = last_time.getTime();
long diff = Math.abs((d1Ms - d2Ms) / 60000);
System.out.println("d1MS: " + d1Ms);
System.out.println("d2MS: " + d2Ms);
System.out.println("Time difference (abs): " + diff)
```

my current_date & last_time values are.

```
current_date: Tue Apr 24 11:07:22 IST 2012
last_time:    Mon Apr 23 04:11:48 IST 2012
```

it displays time difference:1855 but it should be less than 1440 because duration is less than 24 hrs.why it so? and what is the solution to get proper difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1855 is the correct answer:

```
11:07:22 - 04:11:48 == ~31 hours == 1855 minutes.

11am on the 23rd - 24 hours is
11am on the 22nd - ~7 hours is
4am on the 22nd which is your second date.
```

Your solution should work fine.

Comment: I've retrieved both the values from database tables.and 23rd april's time was 4 PM not AM and 24 april is 11AM.So I am not getting why is it so?

Comment: `04:11:48` is `4am` in `24 hour time`, `16:11:48` is `4pm`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, The problem was in values of tables..values which i was inserting in tables through cal.gettime() were in two different formats(12hrs and 24hrs) so after retrieval it was displaying wrong output.

Comment: Interesting, so the values you inserted were in 12 hour time and the values you retrieved were in 24 hour time? Time is a bitch if you're not careful, no doubt.

Comment: Yeah,Just like that... one should always check for capital H and small h while setting the format of time otherwise above problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

//Here is an other solution to calculate the time difference

```
String dateLastModified     = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";   
String dateCurrent          = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";

//Formate your time and date
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

java.util.Date date1        = null;
java.util.Date date2        = null;
//parse the values from String to date
date1   = format.parse(dateLastModified);
date2   = format.parse(dateCurrent);

//time in  milliseconds
long timeDiff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    long diffSeconds = timeDiff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = timeDiff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = timeDiff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long diffDays = timeDiff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
    System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
    System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
    System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");
```