# Calculating Time Difference in Java

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have an requirement to calculate the time difference between Lastmodified Time of a file and currentTime of FTP sever on which the file is present.

A file named abc.txt (last modified - July 23 2014 1:00:00 AM ) is present in a US FTP Server. 
I need to get the last modified time stamp (t1) of the file & currentTime of the US FTP server(t2) and calculate the difference in minutes between the two times ( d1,d2 )

Here's what I have so far.

```
Calendar zonedate = Calendar.getInstance(); 
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST")); 
System.out.println("PDT :: "+ formatter.format(zonedate.getTime())); 
String d1 = formatter.format(zonedate.getTime()); 
System.out.println(d1); 
Date d2 = formatter.parse(d1); 
System.out.println(d2);
```

Comment: So which part can't you do?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: This question has been asked countless times on SO. A simple google will find many answers.

Comment: Problem 
1- even tough I am able to retrieve the US FTP timestamp, I am unable to assign to any variable.
2- unable to calc the difference

Comment: Calendar zonedate = Calendar.getInstance();
     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST"));
  System.out.println("PDT :: "+ formatter.format(zonedate.getTime()));
  
  String d1 = formatter.format(zonedate.getTime());
  System.out.println(d1);
  
  Date d2 = formatter.parse(d1);
  System.out.println(d2);

Output od d2 - IST which is not MST

Comment: Here we are solving the same problem
hope this link will help you.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292587/java-date-time-difference/32345585#32345585

Answer (score 1):

use File.lastModified() to get last modified, System.currentTimeMillis() to get CurrentTime.
Subtract them to get the diff in milliseconds.

diff_in_mins = diff_in_milli_seconds/1000/60;

Comment: No.  He wants to know the system time on the FTP server, not the box where this is running.

Comment: File.lastModified() - get me the File Last modified TimeStamp ( which is fine)

But to get the US FTP Server local/current timestamp, what needs to be done?

Comment: oops. Then u must have a service running in the server to return the currentDate.  :( I'm sorry

Comment: Or, if u aren't worried tooo much about the difference in the clocks, then just get the system's date, convert to US timezone and then operate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

1. Create a 1 KB file .
2. Upload the file to the server.Note the time taken to upload the file.
3. Fetch the file again and look at the timestamp it gets.This timestamp minus the time taken to upload the file should give you the server time (approx).

Comment: I can't approach this method, bcz I should not place in FTP Server